# Update Set after delete using a checkbox to delete Set Item

Tags: reactjs, set

I am using a checkbox to select items.

When the checkbox is checked, item is added to a Set stored in state.

When checkbox is unchecked, item is deleted from the Set  stored in state

Upon verifying if item was removed from Set, the function

```
set.has(setItem)
```

returns false.

However when checking the size of the Set, it is as if I did not remove anything.

I'm probably not updating the set to account for the deleted item.

Can anyone help?

my handleChange function below...

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        var checkedItemId = parseInt(e.target.value)
        setCheckedItems(new Set(checkedItems.add(checkedItemId)))
    }else if(!e.target.checked){
        checkedItems.delete(checkedItemId)
        setCheckedItems(new Set(checkedItems))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const checkedItemId = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if (e.target.checked) {
    setCheckedItems(prevState => {
      let newSetCheckedItems = new Set(...prevState.checkedItems);
      return newSetCheckedItems.add(checkedItemId);
    })
  } else if (!e.target.checked) {
      setCheckedItems(prevState => {
      let newSetCheckedItems = new Set(...prevState.checkedItems);
      return newSetCheckedItems.detele(checkedItemId);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//i don't know about the react but i can give you solution in the  jquery.
var new_arr=[];
$(document.body).on('click','.class_name',function(){

var  is_checked = $(this).is(':checked');
var value_check_box = $(this).val();

if(is_checked==true){
// push the value of the check box in the array variable
   new_arr.push(value_check_box);
 }else{

 

var removeItem = value_check_box  // it is the value when the user uncheck the uncheckbox;

new_arr = jQuery.grep(new_arr, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});


};
})
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: what you dont understand  in this code. please describe  me

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a deep copy of the set.
Do the adding/removing operations on that deep copy.
Then update the set with the deep copy.